# How to solve permutations

Tags: geometry, permutations

Vanessa, Samantha, Hannah, and Jordyn are all part of a 12 member volleyball team. Four members of the team are randomly selected to fill the water jug for the day. What is the probability that all four of them will be chosen?

Comment: Welcome to math.se.  how many ways are there to choose any 4 out of 12 ?

Comment: You would benefit by looking up "combinations" via google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number of ways to select 4 people out of the 12 in the volleyball team - $^{12}C_{4}$

Out of these combinations, there is only 1 which has all 4 of the required people, Vanessa, Samantha, Hannah, and Jordyn.

So the probability becomes $\frac{1}{^{12}C_{4}}$

Also, do not tag a question by geometry if it isn't about geometry at all. Thanks